# How to get exact value from raw json string using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I am getting Json output(Missing quotes in jsonString) from my 3rd party API I wan to parse the output and get one of the property value.

Below are the sample code:

```
echo "Hello World!"
testValue='[{name: bhanu,dept:test}]'
echo " test value " $testValue
echo "$testValue" |  jq -r '.[0].name
```

Getting below error:

parse error: Invalid literal at line 1, column 8

Can you please help me on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is the correct syntax:

```
   echo '[{"name": "bhanu","dept":"test"}]' | jq  -r '.[0].name'
   bhanu
```

in your case(json not stringified) you can use a little help from sed:

```
  echo '[{name: bhanu,dept:test}]' | sed  's/[a-zA-Z]\+/"&"/g' | jq -r '.[0].name'
 bhanu
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but when I am getting the response from 3rd pary API the quotes are missing.  Sample response: [{name: bhanu,dept:test}]   Is there any way to parse this sample response using JQ

Comment: updeted my answer with a possible option via sed

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @R2D2, if you wish to use jq, one option would be to modify the value of testValue so that it is valid JSON, e.g. manually or using some text-wrangling tools.

There are potentially two other options you might wish to consider:

- change whatever it is that is producing the JSON-like text so that it produces JSON or some JSON variant for which a converter to JSON exists
- modify the value of testValue so that it is valid as a jq program, e.g.

```
testValue='[{name: "bhanu", dept: "test"}]'
jq -rn "$testValue | .[0].name"
```